# What reason is there to use postcss-loader without plugins?

Tags: webpack, postcss

I've seen a webpack project that uses postcss-loader without any plugins.
All postcss articles I've found speak of using it with plugins, so is there any signficance or reason to use it without plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people use postcss without plugins to transform a css alternative syntax (like SugarSS) to vanilla CSS. No plugins are needed for that, just an alternate parser.

https://github.com/postcss/sugarss#sugarss-to-css